# Как изменить строку на математическое выражение

Tags: строки, kotlin

У меня есть переменная `exp` где хранится значение типа `string`, как я могу изменить на  математическое выражение?

```
fun main() {
    while (true){

        println("Enter the first operand")
        val x = readLine()
        println("Enter operation")
        val operator = readLine()!![0]
        println("Enter the second operand")
        val y = readLine()
        println("Enter the second operation")
        val operator1 = readLine()!![0]
        println("Enter the Third operand")
        val z = readLine()
        println("Enter the third operation")
        val operator2 = readLine()!![0]
        println("Enter the Fourth operand")
        val q = readLine()
        println("Now to see the result enter =")
        val res = readLine()
        val exp = x+operator+y+operator1+z+operator2+q
    
        if (res == "=") {
            println(exp)
        } else {
            println("Something goes wrong")
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

В вашем случае не надо склеивать всё в строку.

Можно сделать множество условий `if` или `when`, в которых проверить, равен ли оператор определенной строке, и если да, выполнить вычисления:

```
while (true){
    println("Enter the first operand")
    val x = readLine()!!.toInt()
    println("Enter operation")
    val operator = readLine()
    println("Enter the second operand")
    val y = readLine()!!.toInt()
    val res1 = when(operator){
        "+" -> x+y
        "-" -> x-y
        "*" -> x*y
        "/" -> x/y
        else -> throw Exception()
    }
    println(res1)
}
```

Comment: для более сложных -- можно вынести when в функцию

Comment: Ок спасибо попробую!!!!!

Comment: Почему всегда забывают про деление на 0?..

Comment: @Эникейщик, почему сразу забывают, оно ожидаемо бросит исключение. А что делать если бросило -- это отдельный вопрос за рамками вопроса

Answer (score 0):

Каким-то образом я получил то, что хотел. Этот символ !! Я понял, что это не очень хорошее решение, и мне придется снова усложнять код для более сложных математических выражений.

```
fun main() {
        while (true){
          var res1 = 0
            println("Enter the first operand")
            val x = readLine()
            println("Enter operation")
            val operator = readLine()
            println("Enter the second operand")
            val y = readLine()
            if(operator == "+") {
                 res1 = x!!.toInt()+ y!!.toInt()
            }
            else if(operator == "-"){
                 res1 = x!!.toInt()-y!!.toInt()
            }
            else if(operator == "/"){
                res1 = x!!.toInt()/y!!.toInt()
            }
            else if(operator == "*"){
                 res1 = x!!.toInt()*y!!.toInt()
            }
            else{
                println("Something goes wrong")
            }
            println(res1)
        }
    }
```